# Python apps to drastically slow down and use 100% CPU after 'yum update' on RHEL server

Tags: python, linux, performance, centos

Processing apps built in Python were listeners for RabbitMQ messages and converted message into another JSON message and re-published it to another exchange.  It used to process over 10,000 messages / minute.  After server update it now only processes 40-50 messages/minute and is using 100% CPU.

I recently updated all the CentOS6 servers running 'yum update' and upgraded some of our packages like Java to 1.7.0_09.  Ever since then the python apps are painfully slow.  We rebuilt the same functionality for one processor in Java to test and it runs over 10,000 / minute so I'm stumped at why python would slow so badly.

Any ideas or things to check?

```
[root@app1 ~]# python --version
Python 2.6.6
[root@app1 ~]# uname -r
2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.x86_64
[root@app1 ~]# java -version
java version "1.7.0_09-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.3.3.el6_3.1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)
[root@app1 ~]#
```

I just checked a box that wasn't updated and this was OS version before update:

```
[root@test1 ~]# uname -r
2.6.32-279.1.1.el6.x86_64
```

So the update from this version to the new version above seems to be the change.  It appears Python is same version on both boxes so that wasn't updated.  I don't know where to look and even tailed the server audit logs as a forum had reported some SELinux permission errors for python apache plugin after RHEL update.

Comment: was python part of the packages updated?  Have you tried re-starting the whole thing (maybe something is un-happy about a package being updated under it and is hanging for ~1s and then timing out).

Comment: I cannot tell if python was updated.  I did restart each box, and several times restart the applications and message bus.  To rule out RabbitMQ we built one of the processors in Java as there was 20K messages in queue and python was only processing about 1/second.  We ran Java in parallel on same box and it cleared 5K messages in 3 seconds.  It looks like Python was 2.6.6 before yum update but when I try update for it's package it says nothing to update.

Comment: someplace in /var/log there should be a log for yum that will tell you exactly what was updated.  Do you have any `while true: ... if : break` style blocking loops in your code?

Comment: I will check and report.  Another techie told me tonight that Python libs are "touchy" on OS versions.  It's amazing a yum update could cause this much trouble.